# Please explain this Bit Swapping code (Java)

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I am attempting to improve at interview style questions.
I came across this:

*Given a 32 bit integer input x, swap its odd and even bits and return the resulting integer. (e.g., bit 0 and bit 1 are swapped, bit 2 and bit 3 are swapped, and so on).
    For example:
    x = 5, Binary code = 0101
    swapOddEvenBits(5) --> 10*

The answer was as follows:

```
public int swapOddEvenBits(int x) {

 return ( ((x & 0xaaaaaaaa) >> 1) | ((x & 0x55555555) << 1) );

}
```

Can someone explain this, please.
Also, why can't I use something like (x & 1010101010101)>>1 instead?
My original attempt to solve this was to convert the ints into binary strings and then swap adjacent chars and then convert back to an int. Would that work?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Your values are `int` literals in hex,

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0xaaaaaaaa));
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(0x55555555));
```

Which outputs

```
10101010101010101010101010101010
1010101010101010101010101010101
```

You **can** replace `0xaaaaaaaa` with `0b10101010101010101010101010101010` and `0x55555555` with `0b1010101010101010101010101010101` for the same results.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.